Finished DMA doesn't call PulseFinishedCallback when using FreeRTOS
I am trying to send data to PWM through DMA just once. It works fine in normal superloop, but when I'm using FreeRTOS the DMA doesn't call HAL_TIM_PWM_PulseFinishedCallback
  HAL_TIM_PWM_Start_DMA(&htim4, TIM_CHANNEL_3, (uint32_t *)pwmData, indx);

void HAL_TIM_PWM_PulseFinishedCallback(TIM_HandleTypeDef *htim)
{
  if (htim->Instance == TIM4){
    HAL_TIM_PWM_Stop_DMA(&htim4, TIM_CHANNEL_3);
  }
}

When not using FreeRTOS it works. With it, it breaks and DMA nonstop sends the last data from pwmData.

Have you started the FreeRTOS scheduler? Interrupts are generally disabled until you do. What priority have you set the timer IRQ at? What have you set configLIBRARY_MAX_SYSCALL_INTERRUPT_PRIORITY to in your FreeRTOS config?

Scheduler is running fine
HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(DMA1_Stream7_IRQn, 0, 0); and hdma_tim4_ch3.Init.Priority = DMA_PRIORITY_VERY_HIGH; and yes I call HAL_DMA_Init afterwards

Run it with the debugger and stop it and see where the program counter is. Possibly you've failed an assertion while executing another ISR, and it's locked in a tight loop. This is typical in FreeRTOS if you get some interrupt priorities wrong (e.g. calling a FreeRTOS function from a high-priority interrupt.)

Problem is that Call Stacks shows <Exception frame> so I can't look how I got to the Interrupt handler where I end up.

You can enable better debugging  in CubeIDE in Debug Configurations->Debugger->RTOS Kernel Awareness. Set to FreeRTOS and whatever Cortex core you have. Then when you pause in the debugger, it should give you call stacks for every task. Also ensure that all tasks have generous stack sizes.
